# Example of a monoid that is not a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

I think part of my issue here may be that I don't know the correct terminology to find an example, as everything that I've attempted to search has been unhelpful.

I'm trying to come up with an example of a monoid where $ac=bc$, but $a\neq b$. My understanding is that for this to be true, $c$ cannot have an inverse, but I'm having trouble coming up with an actual example where this is true.

Comment: Hint: Consider $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ with multiplication for a suitable $n$.

Comment: Also the set $\mathfrak{I}$ of ideals of a given ring $R$. If $I,J$ are rings of $R$, the product is $IJ=\{sr:s\in I,\ r\in J\}$

Comment: Hints : $(\mathbb{N}, +), (X^X, \circ)$ [for most $X$], $([1,+\infty[, \times), (\mathbb{N}, \times),...$

Comment: The natural numbers are an additive monoid but not a group, although they are cancellative (if $a+c=b+c$ then $a=b$). To obtain a noncancellative monoid from a group, simply adjoin a $0$ element (so $0g_1=0g_2$ for any two original group elements $g_1$ and $g_2$)

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for the terminology "cancellation property."  Possibly interesting: if a commutative monoid has the cancellation property, then the [Grothendieck construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_group) gives a group the monoid embeds in.

A commutative monoid without the cancellation property is $M=\{0,1\}$ with $0+x=x$ and $1+1=1$.  (I believe I learned this from *Mathematics Made Difficult* by Linderholm.)

A noncommutative monoid example is $n\times n$ square matrices.  It is not hard to find three matrices $a,b,c$ with $a\neq b$ and $ac=bc$, even without $c=0$.

Comment: Your example is basically $\{0,1\}$ under multiplication, but with the two symbols swapped and the operation denoted by $+$.

Comment: Yes, it is isomorphic, so not just "basically."  This is a simplification of Linderholm's discussion of counting systems where after a certain point it's just "many."  That is, an element where $\text{many}+1=\text{many}$.  I decided $1$ was quite enough.

Comment: I've also seen a monoid with the cancellation property be called an "integral monoid".  (This is standard in logarithmic geometry, a branch of algebraic geometry.)